# $_GET not working for SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use both `$_GET` and `$_POST` in an sql query. The following is my code:

```
<?php
    $assignment = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    echo "$assignment <br>";

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) { 

        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $text = $_POST['comment'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO comments (user, text, assignment) VALUES ('$user', '$text', '$assignment')";
            mysql_query($query) or die('Error, comment failed to post');
    } 
?>

<h1>Add Comment</h1> 
<form action="log_entry.php" method="post"> 
    Name:<br/> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Comment:<br /> 
    <textarea style="height:200px;" type="text" name="comment" value="" ></textarea> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Comment" />
</form>
```

However, the `$assignment` variable does not work in the query. It is echoed properly before the query is made but its value inside the table after the `INSERT` is completed is empty. What exactly is causing this?

Comment: If you want to use both `$_GET` and `$_POST`, then your url needs to include what you want for GET, for example, `log_entry.php?name=something`. By posting to this url, `$assignment` should be `something`.

Comment: The url already has that info

Comment: The **`GET`** arguments have to be specified in the URL *in the form's* `action` *attribute.*

Comment: Oh ok! Got it. Is this way better than the answer written below for any reason?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to combine GET and POST, use a hidden input field:

```
<?php
    $assignment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); // Name is now in POST data, so swap this
    echo "$assignment <br>";

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) { 

        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $text = $_POST['comment'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO comments (user, text, assignment) VALUES ('$user', '$text', '$assignment')";
            mysql_query($query) or die('Error, comment failed to post');
    } 
?>

<h1>Add Comment</h1> 
<form action="log_entry.php" method="post"> 
    <!-- Add hidden input to carry the name -->
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>"/>
    <!-- Rest of the form is the same -->
    Name:<br/> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Comment:<br /> 
    <textarea style="height:200px;" type="text" name="comment" value="" ></textarea> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Comment" />
</form>
```

Comment: This works. But is this the correct way of doing this or should I do what Dave and Darwin suggested in the comments

Comment: My opinion is that this is the correct way to do it, but honestly I don't know for sure. On some frameworks, doing that sort of thing might cause errors but I see no harm when its all custom code.